# Explicit versus master entries

Tags: html, html5-appcache, cache-manifest, application-cache

I am currently building a simple framework allowing developers to create application cache dynamically, modullary and simply and reduce the mistyped resources.

One thing I am now dealing with is what is "stronger" - master or explicit entry?
When I list for example three resources

```
CACHE:
/home
/page1
/page2
```

and each of these pages include the `manifest` attribute and user navigates to all of them, are they considered as master or explicit entries? It can have a huge impact on behavior of the application when developer uses `prefer-online` setting.

I know I can quite easily test it but I did not find the description of it in the specification so every browser can implement it differently... Did I miss anything in the specification? Or is here anyone from working group who can answer my question? Thanks in advance.